# Can an array controller take inputs before "add" is pressed?

Tags: cocoa, nsmutablearray

In Cococa,

Can I link input fields (say a textField) to my array controller so that a new object is added with attributes already populated?

Thanks

Comment: hey.. it seems like.. you want to add some text fields and when user clicks add you want to populate table view with same data.. is this what you want?

Comment: I have made a sample app, which may help you.. here is the link.. https://db.tt/NMWJdmQL

Comment: Please follow the below update answer??

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code as it is done for one textfield:-
Header File

```
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>

@interface testWindowController : NSWindowController
{
    IBOutlet NSArrayController *arrayController;
    NSMutableArray *array;
}
@property(readwrite,retain)NSMutableArray *array;
@end
```

Implememntation file:-

```
#import "testWindowController.h"

@interface testWindowController ()

@end

@implementation testWindowController
@synthesize array;
- (id)initWithWindow:(NSWindow *)window
{
    self = [super initWithWindow:window];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code here.
    }

    return self;
}

- (void)windowDidLoad
{
    NSString *str=@"testValue";
    self.array=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    NSMutableDictionary *dict=[NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
    [dict setObject:str forKey:@"valueText"];
    [self.array addObject:dict];
    [self setArray:self.array];
    [super windowDidLoad];

    // Implement this method to handle any initialization after your window controller's window has been loaded from its nib file.
}
-(NSString *)windowNibName
{
    return @"testWindowController";
}
@end
```

XIB file:-
Follow below steps:-

1) In this file take one arraycontroller and textfield and then connect your arraycontroller to FileOwner.
2) Then in Binding Inspector bind arraycontroller to FileOwners and mention model key path as array.
3) Now bind your textfield to arraycontroller and model key path as "key:" whose name is valueText.